# There are two functions with the same structure, but different details. How to get rid of duplication?

Tags: java, refactoring

So, here is my functions:

```
  private void sendLeft() {
    leftSendersIndexes = newLeftSendersIndexes;
    Agent rightRecepient;
    int rightRecepientIdx = 0;
    Agent leftSender;
    for (int i = 0; i < leftSendersIndexes.size(); i++) {
        rightRecepientIdx = leftSendersIndexes.get(i) + 1;
        rightRecepient = list.get(rightRecepientIdx);
        leftSender = list.get(rightRecepientIdx - 1);
        rightRecepient.setNewLeftMsg(leftSender.getLeftMsg());
        rightRecepient.setLeftMsg(0); // reset left messages
    }
}

private void sendRight() {
    rightSendersIndexes = newRightSendersIndexes;
    Agent leftRecepient;
    int leftRecepientIdx = 0;
    Agent rightSender;
    for (int i = 0; i < rightSendersIndexes.size(); i++) {
        leftRecepientIdx = rightSendersIndexes.get(i) - 1;
        leftRecepient = list.get(leftRecepientIdx);
        rightSender = list.get(leftRecepientIdx + 1);
        leftRecepient.setNewRightMsg(rightSender.getRightMsg());
    }
}
```

They are very similar. The problem is that in first function I have `leftRecepientIdx+1` and after that `leftRecepientIdx-1` and I have `leftRecepientIdx-1` and `leftRecepientIdx+1` in second function. I may to combine two functions in one and add a boolean parameter.  But is there a better way to get rid of duplication?

Comment: They are very similar.  Are they similar enough?

Comment: you can encode the differences perhaps in different behavior classes and use composition to delegate the different behavior ...

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but to me they look sufficiently different that trying to combine them into one would create a total mess of `if`s and ternary operators.

Comment: @PaulBoddington, thank you for your answer! So, it means that there are no duplication or it means that sometimes we have to accept with duplication?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров I think so. `leftSendersIndexes` appears to be a field, and you can't pass fields as parameters (without reflection), so the first line would have to be `if (left) leftSendersIndexes = newLeftSendersIndexes; else rightSendersIndexes = newRightSendersIndexes;`, and it would just get worse from there. Sometimes code repetition is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is with this refactoring:

```
private void sendLeft() {
    leftSendersIndexes = newLeftSendersIndexes;
    send(leftSendersIndexes, -1);
}

private void sendRight() {
    rightSendersIndexes = newRightSendersIndexes;
    send(rightSendersIndexes, +1);
}

private void send(List<Integer> indexes, int direction) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.size(); i++) {
        int recipientIdx = indexes.get(i) - direction;
        Agent recipient = list.get(recipientIdx);
        Agent sender = list.get(recipientIdx + direction);
        if (direction == -1) {
            recipient.setNewLeftMsg(sender.getLeftMsg());
            recipient.setLeftMsg(0); // reset left messages
        }
        else {
            recipient.setNewRightMsg(sender.getRightMsg());
        }
    }
}
```

The `send` method encapsulates the logic based on the `direction` parameter: +1 for right, -1 for left.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which those appears is important, I would suggest merging, but, I have no idea what that would do. Keep them separate, if this was borrowed, this was made on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are some send functions where sender and receiver are different and reset may happen. So I would try to make one function with arguments sender, receiver and boolean reset.